# Do Clickhouse materialized views support population from multiple materialized views?

Tags: clickhouse

Say I have final materialized view which indends to gather data from multiple other materialized views which in hand are updated from their tables by random period of time. So the final data is inconsistent constantly but is intended to be a ReplacingMergeTree which looks like not to cause major problems.

Is this architecture valid or is there a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf https://youtu.be/1LVJ_WcLgF8?list=PLO3lfQbpDVI-hyw4MyqxEk3rDHw95SzxJ&t=7597

Comment: Thanks for the links, Denny. Would you be so kind to elaborate a little? So is this approach valid or not?

Comment: This approach is valid in some cases and not valid in others. It depends do you use linear functions or not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function

Comment: Keep in mind that Materialized View is a trigger that never reads the source table. All cascaded Materialized Views get data from ----->>>>****their cascaded*****<<<--- INSERTs.

Comment: No I am not using linear functions, only aggregates and sums, nothing else. Is the approach valid here then?

Comment: `aggregates and sums` Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean minState, maxState etc., summing functions